# Disk to use it's full space

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, clone, migration

I've recently bought an M2 SSD into my home server, running Ubuntu 20.10.
The original SATA SSD was a 120GB SSD, the one I bought is a 240GB.
I didn't want to install everything from the basics, so I've cloned the SSD, but later I've seen, Ubuntu thinks, the new SSD is only 120GB also.

I'm starting to reach the maximum, even Unify started to panicing about the system SSD getting full...

Could you help me how could I rewrite partitions in terminal?

[image: here is the M2 SSD]

And here you can see, the drive should have more space.

[image: here are disks]

Thanks a lot for every help fellas! :)

Comment: sorry, can't edit the post. /dev/nvme0n1p2 is the new system partition.

Comment: Probably the easiest way out is to start `gparted`, create a new empty partition that fills the rest of the disk, and move `/home` to the new partition. There are many posts about how to do this, including this website.

Comment: @Jos Not necessary to create a new /home

Comment: @heynnema unless they *have* GUI they can't use `gparted` - looks like they said "home server" so my guess is no GUI

Comment: @syluccy Is this a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server installation? Do you have a GUI?

Comment: @heynnema it was an ubuntu server installation, but for some reason after upgrading to 20.04 it turned to be a basic ubuntu installation, with gui.

Comment: @syluccy Please edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted` of the new SSD, then I can make a recommendation. The new SSD replaced the previous SSD, and the previous SSD is no longer connected, correct?

Comment: @heynnema damn...for some reason I can't access GUI again. :/
https://imgur.com/4BgCtOx
do you have any recommendation, for terminal?

Comment: @syluccy Just for fun, type `startx` and see if the GUI comes up. Otherwise we'll have to give you some terminal commands to do what you want. Do you have good backups? The new SSD replaced the previous SSD, and the previous SSD is no longer connected, correct?

Comment: @syluccy Does the server have a CD/DVD drive? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Desktop Live DVD/USB?

Comment: tried to run startx, xinit had to be installed. done with it, now I can run gui again. :)
installed gparted. here is a screenshot of the drive. what should I do with it?
https://imgur.com/JATwjrA
really glad, you're helping me out dude!

Comment: @heynnema, thanks a lot for the help! the final solution was gparted live usb.
had to run a check, and it fixed the drive. thank you again!
https://imgur.com/fSWDhUy

Comment: @syluccy Glad you got it working!